PrimeNG styles being overwritten by SharePoint styles
I have an Angular app on a SharePoint page but the problem is that the SharePoint styles interfere/override the app styles. Not too big a problem as I can append the !important tag to the styles I want to override. This is not practical when it comes to the style libraries such as PrimeNG or Bootstrap that styles the elements or when it comes to maintaining many styles.
It is particularly evident when it comes to elements such as buttons. All the buttons on the page appear grey as per the SharePoint styles coming from
/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css

In particular it has this style in that css file:
 input[type=button][disabled],
    input[type=reset][disabled],
    input[type=submit][disabled],
    button[disabled][disabled]
    {
     border-color:#eaeaea;
     background-color:#f8f8f8;
     background-color:#f8f8f8;
     color:#a6a6a6;
    }

(yes two instances of background-color!)
But libraries such as PrimeNG will have various colours applied to buttons depending on the "state" - error/success/info etc.
I've tried many solutions such as
background-color: unset;

but none of them work;
Is there some way to not have the SharePoint page load that stylesheet or some way to remove the styles it applies.
Ideally I would like the above style to be rendered as
input[type=button][disabled],
        input[type=reset][disabled],
        input[type=submit][disabled],
        button[disabled][disabled]
        {

        }

before the next set of styles are applied.
